# What is the difference between Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

I've discovered that there are many Stack Exchange sites: http://stackoverflow.com, http://apple.stackexchange.com, http://gamedev.stackexchange.com and perhaps others.

What are the differences between these sites, and what is http://stackoverflow.com mainly about?

Where can I find a list of all the Stack sites?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Stack Exchange is a network of sites, of which Stack Overflow is one. They each use the same software but are generally geared towards certain topics... Stack Overflow being geared towards programming, and others being geared towards other particular topics.

You can either check out the FAQ on each site, or sometimes just looking at the name is enough:

> https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

...is a Stack Exchange site geared towards, well, code golfing :)

Comment: ... and programming puzzles, of course :)

Comment: > Stack Exchange is a network of sites, of which Stack Overflow is one.
I heard that Stack Overflow was recently purchased for $1.8 billion. If it's part of the Stack Exchange, then does it mean that the rest of Stack Exchange will be working normally, as only SO was sold?

Answer (score 23):

https://stackexchange.com/sites

(Contains the list of sites with a short description of each; answering both questions).

https://stackexchange.com/about

(Added by infoSetu's edit an introductory overview of stackexchange/stackoverflow).

Answer (score 10):

If you're wondering what Stack Exchange is, I suggest clicking the gen-u-wine<sup>tm</sup> Stack Exchange logo in the upper left hand corner of every site.

[image: stackexchange super-collider multi-dropdown]

There are a bunch of links and information there, which should tell you everything you need to know!

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about is pretty good too...

Comment: I heard that Stack Overflow was recently purchased for $1.8 billion. As it's only a part of the Stack Exchange, then does it mean that the rest of Stack Exchange will be working normally? Or the whole SE was sold?

Comment: @Kusavil Stack Overflow ([the company](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/)) was purchased. It manages and runs the Stack Exchange network, including Stack Overflow (the site).

Answer (score 8):

You could visit each site's FAQ to see what they are all about.  Simply append `/faq` to each domain and you're there!

Like this:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score -5):

Check out
https://stackexchange.com/sites
There, all the stackexchange websites are listed and will give you a nice overview!

Comment: Please check that you are not duplicating an existing answer when you post one of your own, as is the case here. The answer you posted here was also submitted by someone else 2 years ago.