# What is the relation between Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, migration

Although this question is related:
[What is the difference between Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79593/what-is-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange)
it doesn't answer the question of whether or not questions can be moved between these two areas. I understand that the Stack Exchange is a set of websites, but Stack Overflow has an entirely different domain name. Is there any movement of questions between these two sites?

Basically, I understand that everything in SE is under one big conglomerate, but is SO under part of an even larger circle that allows movement and moderation between the two?

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: SO was the first site so it has its own unique name. However, it is just as connected with the rest of the exchange as the newest beta or as this site.

Comment: @TravisJ other bespoke names include superuser, serverfault, askubuntu, etc

Comment: See also: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @gnat are you the answerer under a different account? Marc answered the question well even though the question was confused. Editing the question now would raise this to the top of the stack needlessly in my opinion when it's already been answered correctly (unlike the link which answers a different question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to ask that my question be moved to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165578/282094)  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150277/282094

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> but is SO under part of an even larger circle that allows movement and moderation between the two?

Yes, basically:

[image]

[You can see the entire network here](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

[image]

Comment: The add of entire network part was what I was interested in.